# Jupyter - Not sure if not working or broken link

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to open a notebook with jupyter, by using the following command:

```
jupyter notebook notebook.ipynb
```

I use Linux and python2, I have installed jupyter inside a virtualenvironment with pip.

When I run the command above, what happens is that I get a new screen

> REFRESH(1 sec): http://localhost:8889/notebooks/mylink
>
> This page should redirect you to Jupyter Notebook. If it doesn't, click here to go to Jupyter.

However, there is no dashboard opening automatically. So, I clicked on the link, but I am unable to connect. The weird think is that I don't remember what I did yesterday, but I managed to get through very easily.

Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe there is a problem with the link?

EDIT: If I run

```
jupyter notebook.ipynb
```

I get

> Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook.ipynb': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

which does not make sense, because the file notebook.ipynb is actually there.
If I type

```
jupyter notebook stop
```

I get

> There are no running servers

Comment: ...what happens if you go to `http://localhost:8889` in the browser? Jupyter normally listens on port 8888 by default, so it seems like you might have another session open which might prevent a new tab from opening.

Comment: I tried both, what I get is "Unable to connect" in my browser.

Comment: If you're on linux, try `ps aux | grep -i jupyter`. This will tell you if you have another jupyter instance running; it sounds like you do.

Comment: If I type that command, I can only see one instance, but I might have opened at least two, I was running on different servers. I can't seem to find any way to kill any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is run

```
jupyter notebook
```

and it will automatically open up the browser with my current directory. I then search for my notebook that way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does not work for me, but maybe it did yesterday, not sure about what happened in the meanwhile.

Comment: Never managed to solve this on Linux, but I successfully set up the jupyter-notebook on Mac OS. I chose this as a solution because it is actually all it takes to run properly.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me too. Also their [troubleshooting](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html) could not resolve the issue. You may note the *This Worked An Hour Ago* section.

If you are using environments, try creating a new environment and install jupyter notebook from scratch there. For Anaconda it would look like this:

```
conda create --name jupyter_env

conda activate jupyter_env

conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab

jupyter notebook
```

You may change jupyter_env to a differen name of your liking.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one of these could help you fix this one:

- change url to  `http://127.0.0.1:8889/notebooks/mylink` or `http://0.0.0.0:8889/notebooks/mylink`
- in case proxy or any other network settings set on your browser, disable them and check twice
- if none of them did work, try to enter the url this way: `http://localhost:8888/tree?`

And, provide logs from console might help as well.

And one more thing, just to make sure, why you're connecting via port 8889? did you tried to run jupyter by `--port` command option?

Comment: I have tried the changing the url as you suggested, none of them works. I did not use the     --port option

Comment: Are you using two jupyter notebooks running simultaneously?  
Could you please copy the log message?

Comment: Change port might help, I guess, run it this way: `jupyter notebook --port 8890`

Comment: I managed to quit the other instances. There's not really much log message to report, besides the one I attached above. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: if you need both of them, there might be other options to work with them and just run one notebook.  if you wanna kill those processes, (in the case you're runnin linux)  find the `pid`, this way:  `ps aux | grep jupyter` in your terminal and copy the number into your clipboard. then kill it by `kill <PID>` replace PID before run

Comment: you can also try `pkill jupyter` but, it'll kill all jupyters running

Comment: Yes, I managed to kill those instances. Now I get port 8888 as default, but I'm still unable to connect.

Comment: Unable to connect, so that might be the problem, but I I have no idea about what it means.

Comment: I got another idea, could you check this url with a different browser? or check if your network setting is on its default mode?

Comment: Yes, I checked it first with Firefox, then Chrome, same result. Chrome has default settings, just in case.

Comment: I think I will try again tomorrow, it's late here. But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: that's okay. any way, check your ports and iptable, and check if access mode for files are allowed for the current user you're trying to run those commands.